# UWP XAML compilation error

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am running into the following compilation problem:

```
    error C2039 : 'XamlBindingInfo' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    error C2039 : 'XamlBindings' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    error C3083 : 'XamlBindingInfo' : the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
    error C3083 : 'XamlBindings' : the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
    error C2039 : 'IXamlBindings' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    error C2065 : 'IXamlBindings' : undeclared identifier
    error C2065 : 'pBindings' : undeclared identifier
    error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed.Note : C++ does not support default - int
    error C2448 : 'XamlBindings' : function - style initializer appears to be a function definition
    error C2059 : syntax error : ':'
    error C2065 : 'pBindings' : undeclared identifier
    error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed.Note : C++ does not support default - int
    error C2448 : '_pBindings' : function - style initializer appears to be a function definition
    error C2039 : 'XamlBindingInfo' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    error C2039 : 'XamlBindings' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    error C3083 : 'XamlBindingInfo' : the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
    error C3083 : 'XamlBindings' : the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
```

This happens when none of my page has no `{Binding}` or `{x:Bind}` mark-up. Is this a known bug in the compiler and is there a walk around?

Comment: What's your testing environment? For example, what's your vs version? Does a blank app have this error? Have you tried repair the vs?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT My VS version is `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.0.26228.4 D15RTWSVC` (should be the RTM; I have never updated VS in fear of failure to build). The blank app has no issue. Compilation fails only after I add an `x:Bind` and then decided to remove it as my new design no longer need binding.

Comment: Can you give me your page?

Comment: share some of your UI code please

Comment: Just take the empty page; add something like `<ListView><DataTemplate x:DataType="SomeType"></DataTemplate></ListView>` and then delete it to see the compilation error.

Comment: Does deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders corresponding to your project and re-building it solve the issue?